# How to activate NUMA in HP Proliant DL580 G5 Server?

Tags: linux, hp, hp-proliant, numa

Currently I am working on a task regarding one server with NUMA. The OS running on the server is Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. The server has 4 nodes of 16 cpus: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X7350  @ 2.93GHz, i.e. each node should have 4 cpus.

I installed NUMA API in the OS. And I looked up with $ numactl --hardware

> available: 1 nodes (0)
>
> node 0 cpus: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
>
> node 0 size: 128938 MB
>
> node 0 free: 126845 MB
>
> node distances:
>
> node   0
>
> 0:  10

From the result, you can see there is only one node detected with 16 cpus.

I looked up in the Internet and couldn't find the solution. I already tried to look it up in BIOS, from [Linux Opteron system appears to be UMA but should be NUMA](https://serverfault.com/questions/408915/linux-opteron-system-appears-to-be-uma-but-should-be-numa), but there is no node-interleaving option in my BIOS. so What can I do to solve the problem to enable NUMA in my server?

Comment: 14.x isn't supported on that server by the way

Comment: @Chopper3 thanks for your reply! So that's the reason why I cannot see 4 nodes in numactl --hardware? which means I have to install other linux OS on the server, right? But do you know why in the BIOS, there is no option to enable node interleaving?

Comment: Well certainly HP's driver set would help to set that up correctly, and obviously you won't have that installed, that said I'm kind of surprised it's not just information the OS gets from the BIOS - are you up to date with the BIOS?

Comment: UPDATE - ah damn, just discovered, the DL580 G5 is NOT a NUMA machine!!! surprised me too - it's right on the cusp of that too, the G6 is one - sorry dude but at least we know why right?

Comment: @Chopper3 Thx, buddy! I also didn't notice that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My standard disclaimer about using Ubuntu on bare-metal hardware applies here... It's not blessed or supported by the vendor, and will cause you more pain in the future...

However, the DL580 G5 is an old architecture. There's no NUMA capability. That wasn't available on that platform until the release until the DL580 G7 series.

```
[root@Coast ~]# dmidecode | grep -i proliant
    Product Name: ProLiant DL580 G7
    Family: ProLiant

# numactl --hardware
available: 4 nodes (0-3)
node 0 size: 16129 MB
node 0 free: 5709 MB
node 1 size: 16160 MB
node 1 free: 9162 MB
node 2 size: 16160 MB
node 2 free: 11273 MB
node 3 size: 16160 MB
node 3 free: 12925 MB
node distances:
node   0   1   2   3
  0:  10  21  21  21
  1:  21  10  21  21
  2:  21  21  10  21
  3:  21  21  21  10
```

Comment: Thx for your answer!

Comment: @ZYJ You're welcome. Did this answer your question?

Comment: yeah!thx buddy!